# how to create two records in two modes at a time one having foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Assume i have two models. ModelA & ModelB.ModelB will have Foregin key to ModelA. i want to create each record in both tables one haveing foregin key.

`models.py`

```
Class ModalA(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Class ModelB(models.Model):
   modela = models.ForeignKey(ModalA,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

`serializer,py`

```
class ModelBSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model = ModelB
    fields = "__all__"



class ModalASerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = ModalA
        fields = "__all__"

     def create(self, validated_data):
    return ModalA(**validated_data)
```

I would like to know how to create bot records in tables.

Comment: At which scenario you wanna do it? Your question isn't much clear [to me]

Comment: What's wrong with creating the instance of A, then B referencing A?

Comment: i want to create it using Django REST framework.i dont know how to create

Comment: @gdef_ that is how i wanted.using Django REST framework but i want to create it in one function.i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of way possible to ensure how we can populate two different model with some dependency requirement. Like after insert in model `A` there must be an entry of model `B` or vice-versa. One of well recommended way is to use `django-signal`[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) (post/pre what is more suitable for scenario). I would like to add additional [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) if you haven't work with django-signal you can follow this post.